# Symbolicate crash report without the app binary

Tags: ios, crashlytics, symbolicatecrash, symbolicate, crittercism

I'm investigating how to create a server side iOS crash report symbolication server like Crashlitics or Crittercism or HokeyApp,  from I can see, they only ask the user to upload the .dSYM file then they are able to symbolicate the crash report, I'm wondering how they archive it?  Apple's standard symbolicatecrash command needs the app binary and the .dSYM file being provided together:

> Symbolication - resolving stack trace addresses to source code methods and lines - requires the application binary that was uploaded to the App Store and the .dSYM file that was generated when that binary was built. This must be an exact match - otherwise, the report cannot be fully symbolicated. It is essential that you keep each build distributed to users (regardless of the details of that distribution) with its .dSYM file.

Any one knows the detail? Thanks.

Comment: I may have just accidentally duped this as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163455/dsym-and-binary-required-to-symbolicate-or-just-dsym . I would love to know the answer though!

Answer (score 0):

Symbolication is the process of translating stack traces into a human-readable form by mapping hexadecimal addresses to function names using symbol file. In other words, Symbolication can be defined as the process of de-obfuscating code symbols with debug symbols removed to both reduce package size and make it harder to reverse engineer. Apteligent automatically symbolicates crashes once you have uploaded your app’s symbol file.

For Apple applications, stack traces are reported in hexidecimal characters. Symbolication allows developers to convert these hex strings into human-readable text.

For more information please refer to  and http://support.crittercism.com/articles/knowledge_base/How-does-iOS-Symbolication-work and https://www.apteligent.com/developer-resources/symbolicating-an-ios-crash-report/

Comment: Links are broken